# What is the real benefit of scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I've looked at over 10 pages trying to find the benefit of a scope over any other ActiveRecord class method that returns an ActiveRecord::Relation.

In the following for example why are scopes better than the alternative below it which do the same thing:

```
  #scope :pat1,  lambda {{:conditions => ["name like ?", 'J%']}}    
  #scope :pat2,  lambda {{:conditions => ["id  > 5"]}}  

  def self.pat1
    where("name like ?", 'J%')
  end  

  def self.pat2 
    where("id  > 5")
  end  

  def patx 
    self.class.pat1.pat2.first
  end
```

The documentation over and over again says that scopes are beneficial because they can be chained...

*"All scope methods will return an ActiveRecord::Relation object which will allow for further methods (such as other scopes) to be called on it."*
-[guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

*"The main reason scopes are better than plain class methods is that they can be chained with other methods"*
[http://ruby.railstutorial.org](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users?version=3.1#sec:scopes_subselects_and_a_lambda)

...but the alternative above can also be chained producing the same results.

Just trying to figure out if there's an emperor's new clothes thing going on here.  Even from a syntactic standpoint there appears to be no benefit.  Are they faster- some sources  vaguely suggest that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord scopes are really just syntax sugar wrapped in a best practice, as noted already.

In the 2.x days of Rails, when they were called "named_scope", they mattered a bit more. They allowed easy chaining of conditions for generating a query. With the improvements in Rails 3.x  with Arel, it is simple to create functions for query relations, as you noted. Scopes just provide a simple and elegant solutions for chainable, predefined queries. Having all the scopes at the top of a model improves the readability and helps shows how the model is used.

Comment: Arel I'm assuming means ActiveRecord::Relation.  OK. The syntactic benefits seem debatable to me.  But if they were doing something that standard methods couldn't do in previous versions then that explains it.

Comment: With rails using better syntax is important.  Not for the code base at day 1 (or even 100) but for the code base at day 1000.

Answer (score 3):

When you write a scope, it is essentially doing the same thing.  Here is what the Rails source looks like:

```
    def scope(name, scope_options = {})
      name = name.to_sym
      valid_scope_name?(name)
      extension = Module.new(&Proc.new) if block_given?

      scope_proc = lambda do |*args|
        options = scope_options.respond_to?(:call) ? unscoped { scope_options.call(*args) } : scope_options
        options = scoped.apply_finder_options(options) if options.is_a?(Hash)

        relation = scoped.merge(options)

        extension ? relation.extending(extension) : relation
      end

      singleton_class.send(:redefine_method, name, &scope_proc)
    end
```

The benefits to scopes in this case are that they are the idiomatic way of defining queries, in some cases fewer lines of code, and you can do extensions.

The example in the source looks like this:

```
scope :red, where(:color => 'red') do
  def dom_id
    'red_shirts'
  end
end
```

Which allows you to call `Model.red.dom_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are syntactic short-cuts that basically represent the methods have you have found.
Why better?
The most immediate effect is that 2 lines code is way easier to read and maintain than 9 lines of code.

Rails always seeks a DRY approach and here the repeated `def self.method end`'s are obscuring the actual code.

Comment: Thanks to you and Sean Hill for confirming that its not a matter of speed.  The railstutorial.org link above specifically starts out saying that their alternative implementation using scopes is somehow faster, but its evidently not related to them using scopes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few very interesting differences between scopes and class methods that return relations.

1. It is easier to deal with nil parameters for scopes with a simple `param.present?` check, for class methods you must explicitly return a non-nil relation if a param would cause a nil relation.
2. Scopes are more easily extensible than class methods. Simply pass a block (for instance to deal with pagination) to add the methods. Class methods can be extended but not as elegantly.

For the full rundown see [this post from Plataformatec](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2013/02/active-record-scopes-vs-class-methods/).